# Duplicate ajax requests when clicking a button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function to open the popup.
When the confirm button is clicked, it will process the request

```
function OpenConfirmPopup(title, msg, func) {
        var mymodal = $('#confirmModal');
        mymodal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
        mymodal.find('.modal-body').text(msg);
        mymodal.modal('show');
        $('.btn-confirm').click(function () {
            var args = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
                args.push(arguments[i]);
            window[func].apply(this, args);
        });
    }
```

And here is the caller

```
function ConfirmAttendance() {
    OpenConfirmPopup("Attendance", "Are you sure you want to confirm the attendance?", "ConfirmAndCloseSession");
}
```

And this is the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-confirm" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

If I call `ConfirmAttendance`, then cancel, then call again and click ok, it seems the request is done twice. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I encounter same problem when i have two or more Jquery library reference on a page. so when i removed one of the reference links it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround by unbinding and rebinding the event, using `off` followed by `on`:

```
function OpenConfirmPopup(title, msg, func) {
    var mymodal = $('#confirmModal');
    mymodal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
    mymodal.find('.modal-body').text(msg);
    mymodal.modal('show');
    $('.btn-confirm').off('click').on('click', function () {
        var args = new Array();
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        window[func].apply(this, args);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you attach a new `click` event handler to the button every time the modal is shown. Move that logic outside of the function.

The only issue there is that you will need to pass the `func` variable through the `OpenConfirmPopup()` function to the click handler. This can be done using a `data()` attribute on the element:

```js
function OpenConfirmPopup(title, msg, func) {
  var $modal = $('#confirmModal');
  $modal.find('.modal-title').text(title);
  $modal.find('.modal-body').text(msg);
  $modal.find('.btn-confirm').data('func', func);
  $modal.modal('show');
}

jQuery($ => { 
  $('.btn-confirm').click(function() {
    var args = new Array();
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    window[$(this).data('func')].apply(this, args);
  });
});
```

I'd also question the purpose of creating the `args` array from `arguments`. The two arrays will be identical, so just provide arguments direcly:

```
$('.btn-confirm').click(function() {
  window[$(this).data('func')].apply(this, arguments);
});
```

If you're doing this in order to clone the array use `slice()`:

```
$('.btn-confirm').click(function() {
  window[$(this).data('func')].apply(this, arguments.slice(0));
});
```

Or spread syntax (if the browsers you're targeting support ES6):

```
$('.btn-confirm').click(function() {
  window[$(this).data('func')].apply(this, [...arguments]);
});
```

Comment: It does not seem to work, `$('.btn-confirm').click` seems never gets triggered.

Comment: You need to put it in a document.ready event handler, or run your JS at the end of the body. I've updated the JS with a complete example.

Comment: I still get error. When clicking the "Ok" on the dialog, it cannot get the value of `$(this).data('func')`. It is undefined.

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/xcnbhj18/. The code works fine (although the UI is a little janky due to the quickly thrown together demo)